# Why toolbar = null in fragment?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Why my toolbar equals to null in fragment ?

**Main theme in manifest**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
"Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"
```

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".home.HomeFragment">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**HomeFragment.kt**

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Title"

        Log.i("HomeFragment", "$toolbar")
        return view
    }


}
```

And in logs i get null on toolbar!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously it is null, since you did not assign and init it.

Just add after `view` assigning

```
val toolbar: Toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
```

Comment: But, i have Kotlin extension which directly referes to Views `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_home.*`

Comment: try manually, as far as I know synthetic is not recommended and supported anymore. Or you can try to clean/rebuild, but guess it will not help